# AWS - finding a Linux AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli

How come when I do

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=platform,Values=windows"
```

I get hundreds of results but when I do:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=platform,Values=linux"
```

I get:

```
{
    "Images": []
}
```

or

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=platform,Values=ubuntu"
{
    "Images": []
}
```

Comment: Maybe your EC2 is only Windows images?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As already noted by Khalid the `platform` tag seems only to be set and supported for windows.

You could search for the description instead:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=description,Values=*ubuntu*"
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=description,Values=*linux*"
```

These gives lots of results....

If you are searching for official Amazon AMIs you could check:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=description,Values=*Linux*" "Name=owner-alias,Values=amazon"
```

Answer (score 1):

Although this is not clearly stated by AWS on their [website](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html), but it seems that the `platform` filter in `describe-images` behaves the same way as `describe-instances`. It only accepts `windows` or empty.

> platform - The platform. Use `windows` if you have Windows instances;
>   otherwise, leave blank.

[This reference](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/CommandLineReference/ec2-clt.pdf) explicitly states that the only valid value for the `platform` filter is `windows`. (Page 353)

Comment: If you leave it blank do you get `windows` as well as Linux?

Comment: Testing this out - yes, it does. Bizarre.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to retrieve information for all the available Ubuntu images then you can do:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=name,Values=*ubuntu*"
```

It will return a very long list of results which you can further filter using any of the following filters: *VirtualizationType, Name, Hypervisor, ImageId, State, BlockDeviceMappings, Architecture, ImageLocation, RootDeviceType,  CreationDate, Public, ImageType*. You can even specify the owner(s) of the AMI, an example:

```
aws ec2 describe-images --filters "Name=architecture,Values=x86_64" "Name=root-device-type,Values=ebs" "Name=virtualization-type,Values=hvm" "Name=name,Values=*ubuntu*xenial*" --owners=099720109477
```